# How to rotate schematic with jnbt in minecraft?

Tags: rotation, minecraft

How to rotate schematics 90 or 180 degrees?  I create generator and I want to make auto schematic paste.  It's simple for paste schematic with standard rotation, but I need to rotate this 90 or 180 degrees.

```
public static void SyncPaste(World world, Location loc, File file, boolean air) {
    try {
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        NBTInputStream nbtStream = new NBTInputStream(stream);
        CompoundTag schematicTag = (CompoundTag) nbtStream.readTag();
        stream.close();
        nbtStream.close();
        if (!schematicTag.getName().equals("Schematic")) {
            throw new Exception("Tag \"Schematic\" does not exist or is not first");
        }
        Map<String, Tag> schematic = schematicTag.getValue();
        if (!schematic.containsKey("Blocks")) {
            throw new Exception("Schematic file is missing a \"Blocks\" tag");
        }
        String materials = getChildTag(schematic, "Materials", StringTag.class).getValue();
        if (!materials.equals("Alpha")) {
            throw new Exception("Schematic file is not an Alpha schematic");
        }
        short width = getChildTag(schematic, "Width", ShortTag.class).getValue();
        short length = getChildTag(schematic, "Length", ShortTag.class).getValue();
        short height = getChildTag(schematic, "Height", ShortTag.class).getValue();

        int offsetX = getChildTag(schematic, "WEOffsetX", IntTag.class).getValue();
        int offsetY = getChildTag(schematic, "WEOffsetY", IntTag.class).getValue();
        int offsetZ = getChildTag(schematic, "WEOffsetZ", IntTag.class).getValue();

        byte[] blocks = getChildTag(schematic, "Blocks", ByteArrayTag.class).getValue();
        byte[] blockData = getChildTag(schematic, "Data", ByteArrayTag.class).getValue();

        byte[] rot = getChildTag(schematic, "Data", ByteArrayTag.class).getValue();


        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                for (int z = 0; z < length; ++z) {
                    int index = y * width * length + z * width + x;

                    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
                    at.translate(-(width/2), -(height/2));

                    Block block = new Location(world, at.getTranslateX() + offsetX + loc.getX(), at.getTranslateY() + offsetY + loc.getY(), z + offsetZ + loc.getZ()).getBlock();
                    if (air == false && Material.getMaterial(blockData[index]) != Material.AIR) {
                        if (blocks[index] != 0) {
                            block.setTypeIdAndData(blocks[index], blockData[index], true);
                        } else {
                            throw new Exception("Blocks can't be 0");
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static <T extends Tag> T getChildTag(Map<String, Tag> items, String key, Class<T> expected)
        throws Exception {
    if (!items.containsKey(key)) {
        throw new Exception("Schematic file is missing a \"" + key + "\" tag");
    }
    Tag tag = items.get(key);
    if (!expected.isInstance(tag)) {
        throw new Exception(key + " tag is not of tag type " + expected.getName());
    }
    return expected.cast(tag);
}

}
```